# Passing JVM parameter

Tags: kerberos, jvm

I'm going to install **Kerberos** authentication for **Kafka**. In one phase of the Kafka document, they mentioned that I must Pass the JAAS  locations as **JVM parameters** to each Kafka broker (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_kerberos_brokerconfig) ~> *the second step*.

The presented format is as follow:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
```

Considering I have created kafka_server_jaas.conf file, how should I pass the mentioned location as a JVM parameter?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked many websites and watched many videos, I think the author means that an environment variable must be set.

specifically, this command must be used:

```
# export $KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
```